# Why does the following attribute error occur?

Tags: python, linear-programming, attributeerror

I get the following error when trying to execute the following in Python with the PuLP library

```
for i in range(0, items):
    print('x{0} = {1}'.format(i+1, value('x{0}'.format(i+1))))
```

That is my code which throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/knapsack.py", line 81, in <module>
    print('x{0} = {1}'.format(i+1, value('x{0}'.format(i+1))))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 1990, in value
    else: return x.value()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

My question is why does this not work. Splitting the print statement tends to work correctly.

Comment: what is the value of `items` and `value`

Comment: What is the code for `value()`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, working example

Comment: The value of items is taken as 4 and the function value is from the PuLP Library for Python

Comment: Looks like some python library containing a `value` method is being called. What you are expecting `value('x{0}'.format(i+1))` to return?

Comment: Why not get rid of value and its parenthesis? Unless it's your function, it serves no purpose.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am expecting it to return the value of the variable 'x1'

Comment: Is that a PuLP variable? I suspect that method takes that object, not a string with the name of that object

Comment: Where is x1 variable ?  Is it and value's work dependent on the i variable.  If not do your work out the loop.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, its a PuLP variable

Comment: @cricket_007 is right, you need to pass the object not a string.

Comment: Try `value(eval('x{0}'.format(i+1)))`

Comment: @cricket_007 That worked. What was I doing wrong?

Comment: we can't guess your intention. provide more data about items and value()

Comment: @Mehrdad the intention is clearly to print out all the variables with their values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` method expects a PuLP variable object, not a string with the same name as one.

In order to evaluate your string back to a python variable, you need to `eval` it, so that would look like.

```
value(eval('x{0}'.format(i+1)))
```